Proof by induction $\sum_{k=1}^n k \cdot 2^k \leqslant n\cdot (2^{n+1} - 1)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$
Task
Proof by induction
$\sum_{k=1}^n k \cdot 2^k \leqslant n\cdot (2^{n+1} - 1)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$
What I got so far

Induction start

For $n=1$ one can show that $2^1  \leqslant 1 \cdot (2^{1+1} - 1)$ is true.

Induction requirement

There is at least one $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n k \cdot 2^k \leqslant n\cdot (2^{n+1} - 1)$

Induction end


I have to show that $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k \cdot 2^k = \overbrace{\underbrace{2^1 + 2 \cdot 2^2 + 3 \cdot 2^3 + ... + n \cdot 2^n}_{S_n} + (n+1) \cdot 2^{n+1}}^{S_{n+1}} \leqslant n \cdot (2^{n+1} - 1) + (n+1)\cdot 2^{n+1}$

The RHS can be written as $n \cdot (2^{n+1} - 1) + (n+1)\cdot 2^{n+1} = n \cdot 2^{n+2} + 2^{n+2} - n - 1$

Furthermore one can say $2^{n+2} = 2 \cdot 2^{n+1} = 2^{n+1} + 2^{n+1} \geqslant 2^{n+1} + 1 \Rightarrow 2^{n+1} -1 \geqslant 0$


Problem
Now I don't know how to proceed with this argument.

Hint: consider instead $S_n$ and the next term outside the sum. Now use the inductive hypothesis.

'I have to show that $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} n \cdot 2^n = \overbrace{\underbrace{2^1 + 2 \cdot 2^2 + 3 \cdot 2^3 + ... + n \cdot 2^n}{S_n} + (n+1) \cdot 2^{n+1}}^{S{n+1}} \leqslant n \cdot (2^{n+1} - 1) + (n+1)\cdot 2^{n+1}$' No. What you have to show is that $n(2^{n+1} - 1) + (n+1)2^{n+1}\le(n+1)(2^{n+2}-1)$, i.e. $2^{n+1}\le2^{n+2}-1$.

Note:  you are confusing your indices.  You meant to write $\sum_{k=1}^nk2^k$.
As to the problem:  Simpler to remark that $\sum_{k=1}^nk2^k≤\sum_{k=1}^nn2^k=n\sum_{k=1}^n 2^k$.

@AnneBauval That's it. Thank you.
I have fixed the indices, this should be correct now.

Consider also proving an exact formula: $\sum_{k=1}^n k2^k = (n-1)2^{n+1}+2$. Rewriting the right side as $n2^{n+1} - (2^{n+1}-2)$ shows this implies the inequality you asked about, as $2^{n+1}-2 > n$ for $n \geq 1$.

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the fairly closely related How do you get from $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}{i\cdot 2^i}$ to $2(n-1)\cdot 2^n+2$? and the AoPS thread find the formula, where they each ask to explicitly determine the sum. There's also the somewhat related, but also more general, The behaviour of $\sum k^a 2^k$..

You don't  have to show that $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k \cdot 2^k =\leqslant n \cdot (2^{n+1} - 1) + (n+1)\cdot 2^{n+1}$.  You already KNOW that because you are assuming via induction that $\sum_{k=1}^n k \cdot 2^k \leqslant n \cdot (2^{n+1} - 1)$ for that $n$.  What you have to show is that $ n \cdot (2^{n+1} - 1) + (n+1)\cdot 2^{n+1}\le (n+1)\cdot 2^{n+2}$. Now you have shown $n \cdot (2^{n+1} - 1) + (n+1)\cdot 2^{n+1} = n \cdot 2^{n+2} + 2^{n+2} - n - 1$ so... just factor!  $=(n+1)2^{n+2} -(n+1)= (n+1)(2^{n+2} -1)$.  Ta-da!

BTW I have never quite seen induction presented in the steps you have.  I ... kind of like it.  But it's not conventional and you'll see it done a bit differently in the future.  (No "induction requirement" [which is for $n=1$] but an "induction assumption".  It's not radically different but it is somewhat different.)

@AnneBauval That was a cut and paste error.

You were on the right track but (besides a repeated typo which I just fixed) your solution needs some cleaning, essentially following my initial comment above:

Replace 'Induction requirement There is at least one $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n k \cdot 2^k \leqslant n \cdot (2^{n+1} - 1)$' with:Induction hypothesis: let $n\in\Bbb N$ be such that $S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n k2^k\le n(2^{n+1}-1)$.
Replace '3. Induction end I have to show that $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k \cdot 2^k = \overbrace{\underbrace{2^1 + 2 \cdot 2^2 + 3 \cdot 2^3 + ... + n \cdot 2^n}_{S_n} + (n+1) \cdot 2^{n+1}}^{S_{n+1}} \leqslant n \cdot (2^{n+1} - 1) + (n+1)\cdot 2^{n+1}$' with:I have to show that $$S_{n+1}\le(n+1)(2^{n+2}-1).$$ Since I know  (from the induction hypothesis above) that $$S_{n+1}=S_n+(n+1)2^{n+1}\le n(2^{n+1}-1)+(n+1)2^{n+1},$$I will be done if I manage to prove that the RHS is $\le(n+1)(2^{n+2}-1)$.
Replace 'The RHS can be written as $n \cdot (2^{n+1} - 1) + (n+1)\cdot 2^{n+1} = n \cdot 2^{n+2} + 2^{n+2} - n - 1$' (which is wrong) with:The RHS can be written as $$n(2^{n+1}-1)+(n+1)2^{n+1}=n2^{n+2}+2^{n+1}-n.$$
Replace 'Furthermore one can say $2^{n+2} = 2 \cdot 2^{n+1} = 2^{n+1} + 2^{n+1} \geqslant 2^{n+1} + 1 \Rightarrow 2^{n+1} -1 \geqslant 0$' withFurthermore one can say $$2^{n+2} = 2\cdot2^{n+1} = 2^{n+1} + 2^{n+1} \ge2^{n+1} + 1$$$$\Rightarrow 2^{n+1}\le2^{n+2}-1\Rightarrow n2^{n+2}+2^{n+1}-n\le(n+1)(2^{n+2}-1),$$ which ends the proof.


Thank you Anne, this was helpful after retracing the steps. Since I am no mathematician, can you tell me why you advice to rewrite this ("Replace '...' with:"), excluding the obvious equality error?

Furthermore I would be interested if it is common not to write "trivial" equations / inequalities in mathemathics to provide better comprehension? To be more specific, in your last line you wrote $n2^{n+2}+2^{n+1}-n \leq (n+1)(2^{n+2}-1)$ (a). Wouldn't it be easier to understand to write something like this $n2^{n+2}+2^{n+1} -n=n2^{n+2}+2^{n+1} - n$, now insert $2^{n+1} \leq 2^{n+2}-1$ to get (a)?

Which one(s?) of the 4 advised replacements are you asking about? As for more or less details, this is a personal 'pedagogical' choice, hopefully shared by some (but not all!) other teachers.

I talk about all of them.

For the 1st one: this is how an induction proof has to begin. The induction hypothesis is not that 'there exists $n$ such that $P(n)$' but only $P(n)$ (for some $n$), and we must derive $P(n+1)$ from it (i.e. for such an $n$). Actually, the complete step of induction to be proved was $$(\forall n)(P(n)\to P(n+1))$$ and it has been decomposed, using universal generalization and introduction of premise. For the 2nd one: you confused what you must prove and what you know (see also the other answer).

For the 3rd one: as mentionned, it was false. For the 4th one: your final (and obvious, without what preceded) '$\Rightarrow 2^{n+1} -1 \geqslant 0$' was useless, but what preceded has been used to end the proof.

You are actually done and you did it correctly.
$\require{cancel}$
========
Task
Proof by induction
$\sum_{k=1}^n k \cdot 2^k \leqslant k \cdot (2^{k+1} - 1)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$
What I got so far

Induction start

For $n=1$ one can show that $2^1  \leqslant 1 \cdot (2^{1+1} - 1)$ is true.

Induction requirement

There is at least one $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n k \cdot 2^k \leqslant k \cdot (2^{k+1} - 1)$

Induction end


$\cancel{\text{I have to show}}\color{red}{\text{We know}}$ that $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k \cdot 2^k = \overbrace{\underbrace{2^1 + 2 \cdot 2^2 + 3 \cdot 2^3 + ... + n \cdot 2^n}_{S_n} + (n+1) \cdot 2^{n+1}}^{S_{n+1}} \leqslant n \cdot (2^{n+1} - 1) + (n+1)\cdot 2^{n+1}$ $\color{red}{\text{as we know by the induction requirement }\underbrace{2^1 + 2 \cdot 2^2 + 3 \cdot 2^3 + ... + n \cdot 2^n}_{S_n}\le n \cdot (2^{n+1} - 1) \text{ for this }n}$

The RHS can be written as $n \cdot (2^{n+1} - 1) + (n+1)\cdot 2^{n+1} = n \cdot 2^{n+2} + 2^{n+2} - n - 1\color{red}{=(n+1)(2^{n+2} - 1)\text{ and so we are done.}}$


-$\cancel{\text {Furthermore one can say }2^{n+2} = 2 \cdot 2^{n+1} = 2^{n+1} + 2^{n+1} \geqslant 2^{n+1} + 1 \Rightarrow 2^{n+1} -1 \geqslant 0} \color{red}{\text{ True, but not useful or relevent}}$
